# Couldn't store the card values after version change in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant, shopify-activemerchant

I am having a user signup page where I will enter personal details along with credit card info. User has_many accounts and account belongs_to user. When user is created, account is created and credit card info and address is stored in a subscription table. After account creation, it is going to store_card method in subscription.rb model.
It is working fine when I run the application in Rails 3.2.13 and when I migrated it to Rails 4.2.6, it is not storing the subscription 
details and no error displayed. I upgraded activemerchant gem to 1.47.0 and changed the code in load_billing method in the below controller
from

```
@creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:account].blank? ? nil : params[:account][:creditcard])
```

to

```
@creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:account].blank? ? {} : params[:account][:creditcard])
```

and in the same way @address too.

There is no specific relation but just this line is added in account.rb:

```
has_subscription :user_limit => Proc.new {|a| a.users.count }
```

When I tried to run from console:

```
u = Account.find(1)
u.subscription
```

it is generating subscription columns.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :build_account, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :build_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :load_billing, :only => [:new, :create, :billing]
  def create
    @address.first_name = @creditcard.first_name
    @address.last_name = @creditcard.last_name
    @account.address = @address
    @account.creditcard = @creditcard
    if @account.new_record?
      if @account.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Account was created.'
        bypass_sign_in(@user)
        redirect_to session[:previous_url] || user_reports_path(@user)
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    else
      @user.account_id = @account.id
      if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = 'User was created.'
        bypass_sign_in(@user)
        redirect_to session[:previous_url] || user_reports_path(@user)
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  def billing
    @user = current_user
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    if request.put?
      @address.first_name = @creditcard.first_name
      @address.last_name = @creditcard.last_name
      puts @address.first_name
      if @creditcard.valid? & @address.valid?
       if @subscription.store_card(@creditcard, :billing_address => @address.to_activemerchant, :ip => request.remote_ip)
         flash[:notice] = "Your billing information has been updated."
         redirect_to settings_path(@user)
       end
      end
    end
  end
  protected

  def resource
    @account ||= current_account
  end

  def build_account
    @account = params[:account_name].blank? ? Account.new : Account.find_by_name(params[:account_name])
  end

  def build_user
    @account.user = @user = User.new(params[:account].blank? ? nil : params[:account][:user])
  end

  def load_billing
    @creditcard = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(params[:account].blank? ? {} : params[:account][:creditcard])
    @address = SubscriptionAddress.new(params[:account].blank? ? {} : params[:account][:address])
  end

end
```

subscription.rb:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :creditcard, :address
  def store_card(creditcard, gw_options = {})
    # Clear out payment info if switching to CC from PayPal
    destroy_gateway_record(paypal) if paypal?

    @response = if billing_id.blank?
      gateway.store(creditcard, gw_options)
    else
      gateway.update(billing_id, creditcard, gw_options)
    end

    if @response.success?
      if active_card = @response.params['active_card']
        # Stripe token-based response
        self.card_number = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-#{active_card['last4']}"
        self.card_expiration = "%02d-%d" % [active_card['exp_month'], active_card['exp_year']]
      else
        self.card_number = creditcard.display_number
        self.card_expiration = "%02d-%d" % [creditcard.expiry_date.month, creditcard.expiry_date.year]
      end
      set_billing
    else
      errors.add(:base, @response.message)
      false
    end
  end

  def card_storage
      self.store_card(@creditcard, :billing_address => @address.to_activemerchant) if @creditcard && @address && card_number.blank?
    end

  def set_billing
      self.billing_id = @response.token
    end

end
```

account.rb:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

validate :valid_subscription?, :on => :create

  def valid_subscription?
    puts "valid_subscription**************************"
    return if errors.any? # Don't bother with a subscription if there are errors already
    self.build_subscription(:plan => @plan, :next_renewal_at => @plan_start, :creditcard => @creditcard, :address => @address)
    if !subscription.valid?
      errors.add(:base, "Error with payment: #{subscription.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}")
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Please help whether I need to use strong params and how or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be good to see `Account` model as well, but based on your code it looks like you never save credit card info. Method `store_card` just assigns values, but never saves them into database. The simplest solution would be just call `self.save` in your `store_card` method.

```
 if active_card = @response.params['active_card']
    # Stripe token-based response
    self.card_number = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-#{active_card['last4']}"
    self.card_expiration = "%02d-%d" % [active_card['exp_month'], active_card['exp_year']]
  else
    self.card_number = creditcard.display_number
    self.card_expiration = "%02d-%d" % [creditcard.expiry_date.month, creditcard.expiry_date.year]
  end
  self.save
```

Comment: @rk x: In my older version it hits this model and method, currently it is not coming into this model or method. That is the problem.

Comment: I added account model, please check.

Comment: so  just be clear, does validation ```valid_subscription?```  in your Account model work?

Comment: You are not saving your subscription, you just building it. Unless you have autosave enabled for this association(```has_many :subscriptions, autosave: true```) you have to call save on this subscription.